# Cannot trust gazebo2.2. Recommended way of using Gazebo with ROS Indigo?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I got continuos errors when using Indigo with Gazebo.

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13061/built-world-cannot-save-as-the-dialogue-is-empty/

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13054/namespaces-error-waiting-for-1second/ (this error arises when Installing indigo-full and launching gazebo)

Am I doing this in a wrong way or should I stop using indigo with gazebo as this version was abandoned and not maintained well any longer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13062/cannot-trust-gazebo2.2.-recommended-way-of-using-gazebo-with-ros-indigo?/) by [puav](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2534/puav/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-04-11

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo 2.2 reached [end of life](http://gazebosim.org/#status) on January 2016, so it is recommended you upgrade to a newer version.

See [these](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions#UsingaspecificGazeboversionwithROS) tutorials on how to use a specific version of Gazebo with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0